# Бинарное дерево поиска: структуры

Tags: c++

Вот задание:
1) преобразование структур в дерево поиска;
Что такое дерево поиска, я понял, но подскажите,пожалуйста, как это реализовать, желательно с каким-нибудь примером.

Comment: Вам стоило бы сформулировать вопрос более конкретно, не в виде "задания".

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-data_structures_07/ - сдесь отлично объяснено и пример кода на чистом Си. Все предельно понятно.

Answer (score 0):

У нас есть какая-то структура, например структура "слово".
Она может содержать различные поля, для простоты здесь 
только массив char

```
struct Word
{
   char key[100];
};
```

Согласно первому пункту задания, преобразуем эту структуру
в узел бинарного дерева поиска. Узел бинарного дерева
будет хранить  ключ ( уже есть массив char), значение и  указатели на  правого-левого ребенка.

Вот что вышло:

```
struct Word
{
   char key[100];
   size_t value;

   Word * left;
   Word * right;   
};
```

Структура "слово" у нас есть, поработаем с текстом.

Задача:  для каждого слова в тексте подсчитать, сколько раз оно  там встречается

Решение: Будем вставлять в дерево слова из текста с соблюдением свойства упорядоченности .
С Википедии:

> У всех узлов левого поддерева произвольного узла X значения ключей
>   данных меньше, нежели значение ключа данных самого узла X.
>  У всех
>   узлов правого поддерева произвольного узла X значения ключей данных
>   больше либо равны, нежели значение ключа данных самого узла X.

Одновременно считаем слова таким образом: если  слово в дереве
еще не встречалось, то полю value присваиваем единицу, если такое слово 
уже встречалось, то увеличиваем value: value + 1

```
Word* insert(Word* node, char * key)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
    {
        node = new  Word;
        strcpy(node->key, key);
        //такое слово 
        //еще не встречалось,  value присваиваем единицу
        node->value = 1;
        node->left = node->right = nullptr;
        return node;
    }

    int res = strcmp(node->key, key);
    //если слово уже встречалось, увеличиваем value: + 1
    if(res == 0)
        node->value++;
    else
    {
        if (res < 0)
            node->left = insert(node->left, key);
        else// if (res > 0)
            node->right = insert(node->right, key);

    }

    return node;
}
```

Теперь мы можем напечатать в неубывающем порядке, с помощью рекурсии, 
каждое слово и его количество в тексте.

```
void inorder(Word *node)
{
    if (node != nullptr)
    {
        inorder(node->left);
        std::cout << node->key << " " << node->value << "\n";
        inorder(node->right);
    }
}
```

Следующая задача, найти минимальное, максимальное слово в тексте:

Дерево словами уже заполнено и упорядочено в лексикографическом порядке.
 Для поиска минимального слова нужно спуститься от корня 
влево пока не упрёмся в NULL:

```
Word * MinWord(Word * node)
{
    while (node->left != nullptr)
        node = node->left;
    return node;
}
```

Для поиска максимального аналогично, но идем вправо, спускаемся от корня 
 пока не упрёмся в NULL:

```
Word * MaxWord(Word * node)
{
    while (node->right != nullptr)
        node = node->right;
    return node;
}
```

Функция main:

```
int main()
{
    Word* root = nullptr;

    char text[] = "The first two rotations are single rotations and the next two rotations are double rotations";
    char tmp[100];
    std::stringstream ss(text);

    // разбиваем текст на слова, заполняем дерево 
    while (ss >> tmp)
        root = insert(root, tmp);

    // вывод  слов и их  количества 
    inorder(root);

    // минимальное, максимальное слово:
    Word* minWord = MinWord(root);
    std::cout << "Min Word: " << minWord->key << std::endl;

    Word* maxWord = MaxWord(root);
    std::cout << "Max Word: " << maxWord->key << std::endl;
}
```

Результат:
two 2
the 1
single 1
rotations 4
next 1
first 1
double 1
are 2
and 1
The 1
Min Word: two
Max Word: The

Comment: Спасибо, ребята) Почитаю Ваши материалы. Я пока ждал ответы, тоже нашел материал, где все доходчиво объясняется. Есть теперь от чего отталкиваться.